# Tag synonym [cheat] → [cheats]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

It seems we have both [cheat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheat) and [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats). I request merging into [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag mergification complete!!!!

Comment: `MERGIFICATE. MERGIFICATE. MERGIFICATE.`